# I want to display a list of categories on my HTML page from a Django 2.2 model but having trouble

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-2.0

I am creating an e-commerce website with Django, and on the products page I have a sidebar with category selections. I would liek to dynamically display the category selections according to the category choices given in the product model.

Here is an image of the HTML (please don't judge the content or store type;-):

[image]

Here is the model for toy products:

```
class ToyProduct(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    stock_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=TOY_CATEGORY_CHOICES, 
    max_length=2, default='FW')
    brand = models.CharField(choices=TOY_BRAND_CHOICES, max_length=2, 
    default='NB')
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here are the category choices, defined within a tuple on the models.py file:

```
TOY_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('FW', 'For Women'),
    ('FM', 'For Men'),
    ('DD', 'Dildo'),
    ('VB', 'Vibrator'),
    ('LX', 'Luxury'),
    ('KT', 'Kit'),
    ('BP', 'Butt Plug'),
    ('PM', 'Prostate Massager'),
    ('AB', 'Anal Bead')
)
```

Here is the view in views.py

```
def products_sextoys_view(request):

    context = {
        'header': 'Sex Toys',
        'toy': ToyProduct.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'products/sextoys.html', context)
```

Here is the HTML file thus far:

```
<section id="products-framework">
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2" id="category-column">
                <h1 class="text-center">Category Choices</h1>
                <h4><strong>Category</strong></h4>

                <a href="#"><h3></h3></a>


                <hr class="newhr">

                <h4><strong>Brands</strong></h4>

                <a href="#"><h3></h3></a>

                <hr class="newhr">
            </div>
```

As you can see I have tried a for loop but this isn't outputting anything. I have tried several things, and various ways of typing out the for loop and referring to the choices object within the ToyProducts Class, however nothing seems to be working. There will be hundreds of pages with a sidebar and various choices within the models and so hard coding each and every page is not what I would like to do. I would like to be able to loop through the catrgory options and display them as a list down the left hand side

Many thanks!

Comment: Please, always try to put the formatted code instead of screenshots. It's easier for people to help if they can copy and modify the code, and not write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Now that we can see the view code. `ToyProduct.objects.all()` is a Queryset, which has no attribute `category`, so when you try to access `toy.category` you get nothing. Looping through toys to get categories will cause problems even if done correctly though. The best plan is definitely to just make sure the list of categories is available in the template context.

i can't be more specific or definitive because you haven't shown your code for the view, but: `toy.category` would most likely be a reference to the category assigned to whatever instance of `ToyProduct` is available in the template context as `toy`. to loop through all categories you'd want to make `TOY_CATEGORY_CHOICES` available to the template.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I thought I had, I have added it above, thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the view. In the future it may help you to know that copying and pasting code blocks is preferred to posting images - it makes it easier for folks to copy and edit your code while answering, and is more accessible/readable.

Comment: Noted, thank you for your time! I'll make sure I copy and paste from here on

Answer (score 0):

So I thought it would be possible to avoid having to create multiple category lists however apparently not, I created a dictionary categories and as the value created a list, containing each category option as a string. I then looped through this string within the HTML:

```
def products_sextoys_view(request):

    context = {
        'header': 'Sex Toys',
        'toy': ToyProduct.objects.all(),
        'categories': [
            'For Women',
            'For Men',
            'Dildos',
            'Vibrators',
            'Luxury',
            'Kits',
            'Butt Plugs',
            'Prostate Massagers',
            'Anal Beads'
        ]
    }

    return render(request, 'products/sextoys.html', context)
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="col-2" id="category-column">
                <h1 class="text-center">Category Choices</h1>
                <h4><strong>Category</strong></h4>

                {% for category in categories %}
                <a href="#"><h3>{{ category }}</h3></a>
                {% endfor %}

                <hr class="newhr">

                <h4><strong>Brands</strong></h4>

                <a href="#"><h3></h3></a>

                <hr class="newhr">
            </div>
```

I will be repeating the process for brand options too, thanks all!

Comment: It would be a better idea to create a separate model for categories and then have a `ManyToManyField` in your product model. That way if you have a new category some time later, all you'll have to do is create a new object. Otherwise you'll have to modify the code for such trivial additions.

Comment: Would you be able to explain manytomany fields and how they're used, I've seen them and tried understanding them but not quite got it yet, maybe because I haven't found a need for them yet.

Comment: This is a comprehensive document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/